# Spring MVC Hibernate without xml using DriverManagerDataSource how to map properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have these configurations inside `spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml` file which I would like to transfer to a Java config class:

```
<!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_User_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent" />

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

I have these Java config files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("myappname")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource bds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        bds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Drive");
        bds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myappname");
        bds.setUsername("postgres");
        bds.setPassword("mypass");

        return bds;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure however how to map properties like `minPoolSize` or the `SessionFactory` bean.

I also have this `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myappname</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypass</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="myappname.entity.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

PS I'm using Spring MVC, **not** Spring Boot. I don't want to use Spring Boot for this project, because I want to understand how to do it with Spring MVC, so please, don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a working code that I used to learn spring - hibernate integration.

You already have the datasource configured and you may modify the code as per your requirement. The transaction and session management is taken care of in this configuration .

```
package rg.so.poc.txn.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("schema.sql")
                //.addScript("data.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "rg.so.poc.txn.entity" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return emFactoryBean;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```